# RGBimage array and creating ppm file

Tags: java, arrays, rgb

This is part of university task

I'm given a class named RGBColor without private access(but with info on what each method/constructor does)
the object is (r,g,b): r for red, g for green, b for blue, each of them represent a number between 0-255

I need to write a new class named RBGImage based on RBGColor, and the class object is a two-dimensional array storing RGBColor objects.

My struggle is to create a ppm file in order to check the program and I have no idea how to do it. This is what I did so far:

```java
public class RGBImage
{
    RGBColor[][] _image;
    public RGBImage(int rows , int cols){
        
        _image=new RGBColor[rows][cols];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
                _image[i][j]=new RGBColor(_image[i][j]);
        
}

public RGBImage(RGBColor[][] pixels) {
      
int hight=pixels.length;
int width=pixels[0].length;
_image=new RGBColor[hight][width];
        for(int i=0;i<hight;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
                _image[i][j] = new RGBColor(pixels[i][j]);
                ;   

} 


public RGBImage(RGBImage other)
{
_image = other._image;    
}

public int getHeight()
{
    int hight = _image.length;
    return  hight;
}

public int getWidth() {
int width = _image[0].length;

return width;

}

public RGBColor getPixel(int row,int col)
{
int _red = _image[row][col].getRed();
int _green = _image[row][col].getGreen();
int _blue = _image[row][col].getBlue();
return new RGBColor(_red,_green,_blue);    
}

public void setPixel(int row,int col,RGBColor pixel)
{
int _red = pixel.getRed();
int _green = pixel.getGreen();
int _blue = pixel.getBlue(); 
// set if to do nothing
if(row <= _image.length && col <= _image[0].length) 

    
_image[row][col].setRed(_red);
_image[row][col].setGreen(_green);
_image[row][col].setBlue(_blue);    
}

public double[][] toGrayscaleArray() {
     int width = _image[0].length;
     int hight = _image.length;
    
     double[][] grayScale = new double[hight][width];
        
        for(int i=0;i<hight;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++)
                grayScale[i][j]=_image[i][j].convertToGrayscale();
        
        return grayScale;
}


public boolean equals (RGBImage other)
{
if(_image == other._image)
return true;
return false;    
}
```

Sorry I couldn't provide any documentation

Comment: Have you looked at [the PPM format description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example) ? What exactly is the problem ? Is there something in the file format you do not understand ? Or do you need help with IO operations ? In your example, I do not see any attempt for writing the PPM file. You should start by creating a function (or a class)that takes an RGBImage and a File (or a java.nio.Path) as arguments, in charge of writing the image in the file. You can then post the method with comments to show where you need help in the writing process. Regards.

Comment: yeah I have no idea how to make the transition from the code i wrote to creating actual file on my pc in order to check it,this is just the beginning of the course and we focusing on two dimensional arrays and loops atm and it seem a bit advanced,I need to search for a code that connect between the two dimensional array in RBGImage to some code that creates a file based on that? thanks

Comment: I think you must write it yourself. The ppm file is very close to the representation of an image in memory, so once you've understood how to use a writer, writing the ppm will mostly consist in two loops to write every pixel of every line of your image. Try to code a method with the following signature : `public static void writeImage(RGBImage input, Path output) { }`. To ease the task, you can start by using a BufferedWriter (see java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter()) to create a text encoded ppm file (see wikipedia link in my first comment).